# PostgreSQL 9.3: Pass values to only selected parameter in function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have to table with four columns as shown below:

**Table**:

```
create table fortesting
(
    cola int not null,
    colb timestamp null,
    colc text null,
    cold int null
)
```

Now I want to create a function to insert the records into the table
with the dynamic sql so I used language plpgsql function as shown below.

**Function**:

```
create or replace function functionTest
(
    p_cola int,
    p_colb timestamp = null,
    p_colc text = '',
    p_cold int = null
)
returns void as

$body$

Declare v_query varchar;

begin

    v_query := 'insert into fortesting(cola,colb,colc,cold) values('||p_cola||','''||p_colb||''','''||p_colc||''','||p_cold||')';

    RAISE INFO '%',v_query;

    EXECUTE v_query;

end;

$body$

language plpgsql;
```

**Calling FUNCTION**:

I only pass two values to two parameter rest should go null into table.

```
SELECT * FROM  functionTest( p_cola := 1, p_colc:='abc');
```

**Error Details**:

```
INFO:  <NULL>

ERROR:  query string argument of EXECUTE is null
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function functiontest(integer,timestamp without time zone,text,integer) line 11 at EXECUTE statement
```

Comment: when you compose SQL command, you have to use correct quoting functions for parameters: `quote_ident` or `quote_literal` or use `USING` clause. **Without it the code is SQL injection vulnerable!**

Comment: It is pretty important for you or for any reader. This bug is stupid and still pretty wide. When you use syntax advised by @a_horse_with_no_name, then your code will be faster, cleaner and safe.

Comment: @Pavel Stehule, Okay!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that a concatenating a `null` value with something returns a `null` value, even if other elements are not null.

But you don't need dynamic SQL for this, you can pass the parameters directly:

```
insert into fortesting(cola,colb,colc,cold) values ($1, $2, $3, $4);
```

If you do want to use dynamic SQL (even though it's not needed) you should do the same:

```
v_query := 'insert into fortesting(cola,colb,colc,cold) values ($1, $2, $3, $4)';

RAISE INFO '%',v_query;

EXECUTE v_query
    using p_cola, p_colb, p_colc, p_cold;
```

To execute the function use:

```
SELECT functionTest( p_cola := 1, p_colc:='abc');
```

do not put it into the `from` clause as it does not return a "table"

Comment: Can you please help me for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273829/postgresql-export-data-from-sql-server-2008-r2-to-postgresql-9-5