# PostgreSQL: Export data from SQL Server 2008 R2 to PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: postgresql

I have a table to export data from SQL Server to PostgreSQL.

Steps I followed:

Step 1: Export data from SQL Server:

```
Source: SQL Server Table
Destination: Flat file Destination 
Table Or Query to copy: Query
```

Query:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(convert(varchar(max),id),'NULL') + '|'
    +COALESCE(convert(varchar(max),Name),'NULL') + '|'
    COALESCE(convert(varchar(max),EDate,121),'NULL') AS A
FROM tbl_Employee;
```

File Name: file.txt

Step 2: Copy to PostgreSQL.

Command:

```
\COPY tbl_employee FROM '$FilePath\file.txt' DELIMITER '|' NULL AS 'NULL' ENCODING 'LATIN1'
```

Getting Following error message:

```
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0xc1 0x20
```

Comment: Well, as it says, you've got a byte sequence that isn't valid UTF8. I would guess that the original source database is not in UTF8. To minimise transition error, you're gonna want to to configure Postgres's back end to use whatever encoding the original database had.

Comment: That error message is surprising. Which PostgreSQL version is this? What do you get for `SHOW client_encoding;` and `SHOW server_encoding;`?

Comment: Both encoding are 'UTF8'.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: I don't think server or client encoding are the key here. It's the file or its encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tell Postgres the source would be encoded as LATIN1:

> ```
> \copy ... ENCODING 'LATIN1'
> ```

But that's either not the case or the file is damaged. Else we would not see the error message. What is the true encoding of `'$FilePath\file.txt'`?

The current `client_encoding` is not relevant for this since, [quoting the manual on `COPY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html):

> `ENCODING`
>
> Specifies that the file is encoded in the *`encoding_name`*. If this option is omitted, the current client encoding is used.

(`\copy` is jut a wrapper for SQL `COPY` in psql.)

And your `server_encoding` is largely irrelevant, too - as long as Postgres can use a [built-in conversion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#CONVERSION-NAMES) and the target encoding contains all characters of the source encoding - which is the case for LATIN1 -> UTF8: `iso_8859_1_to_utf8`.

So the remaining source of error is your file, which is almost certainly not valid LATIN1.

Comment: I realize that `client_encoding` shouln't come into play here, but I am still clueless. If the file contained the byte sequence `C1 20`, then it should be converted to `'Á '` without error. Sowhat happens must be that `iso8859_1_to_utf8` turns some single byte into `C1 20`, but I cannot see how that could happen... That function doesn't throw any such error messages.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Good points. I am not entirely sure how the error is generated exactly. I ***guess*** the source file has illegal bytes for LATIN1 (damaged file or wrong encoding), the conversion does its job in good faith and produces illegal UTF8 for the illegal input. To generate a more helpful error message, Postgres might test (more thoroughly) whether the source is legal and not wait with the test until after the conversion - which might be more expensive, which is why that isn't implemented. Or the OP made a c/p mistake in the question. Just speculating here ...